# windows server 2008 tasks\cmd programs

Tags: windows-server-2008, scheduled-task

when I run a task on windows server 2008 I can't see the windows of it. how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry If I didn't understand it properly but what do you mean by "I can't see the windows of it" ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to run them interactively (from a command prompt) to see them in a window. Otherwise the process(es) run in the background and thus do not have a window associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

Your task needs to run in interactive mode.  You can run `at.exe /interactive` or [schedule with schtasks.exe as described here](http://www.fendy.org/learned/running-schtasks-with-interactive-mode/).